# How to make codeigniter folder my root folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, root

I have put the codeigniter files in a separate folder called CI_Folder. This folder is in the root directory. index.php also resides in the root directory.

Currently when I enter the URL www.xyz.com, index.php is displayed.

I want to make a website in codeigniter so that when someone enters www.xyz.com he should see the webpage which the controller is loading i.e he should be redirected to the CI_Folder.

Is this possible? If yes how should I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: directly put all files and folder of `codeigniter` in root directory.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar  is there no other way. I wanted to keep the root directory clean

Comment: then use htaccess for this. But as i know codeigniter does not have lots of folders and files.It only has 2-3 folders, index.php and htaccess files only.

Comment: Your root directory is accessible to public?

Comment: @Stacy, If possible you should always place the codeigniter `system` and `application` folders in the directory above your webroot (folder that contains your index.php), so that they are inaccessible to the public.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know why you want to do that, anyway it's as easy as:

1. Place the codeigniter's index.php in your root directory
2. Open said index.php and change the `$system_path` and `$application_folder` to reflect the position of your folders. For example, if you place the whole "codeigniter" folder in you root, it would be:

   ```
    $system_path = './codeigniter/system';
    $application_folder = './codeigniter/application';
   ```

This is your folder structure now:

```
[webroot]
     index.php  (taken out from codeigniter package)
     codeigniter/
          application/
          system/
```

Answer (score 0):

In `index.php` file of the codeigniter(in codeigniter folder) there is option to specify location and name of `system` folder and `application` folder.
Specify them and use `.htaccess`

I have my following rewrite options

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
 </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Modify as appropriate for your requirement.
I hope it helps.